# Serialization and deserialization of > 'System.Action' ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var httpContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        httpContent.Add(stringContent, "params");

        using var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
```

I was trying to send http request, but got an exception on **PostAsync()** line

> System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of
> 'System.Action' instances are not supported. Path: $.MoveNextAction.

Comment: You probably forgot to materialize your DB query, and this line `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)`  is causing the exception. Can you show the code where you fetch data from your database? or how `data` is being constructed?

Comment: data is simply created as usual object data= new DRequest()
        {
            Vvs= configuration["XXX:xxx"],
            IssueDate = issueDate,
            ExpireDate = expireDate
        };

Answer (score 5):

Adding `await` in controller before service method invokation solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

Switch the return type for the controllers to `Task<IActionResult>`.

I faced this issue when I was switching to using the Task Parallel Library's async-await implementation but let my controllers return an `IActionResult` instead of a `Task<IActionResult>`

Answer (score 0):

So without knowing the structure of the `data` I can only assume the following. You have a Class that has a definition of `Action` in it. Something like the following.

```cs
public class YourData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Action TheAction { get; set; }
}
```

When you try to serialize it you receive the exception. If that is what you are experiencing you will need to update your class that represents your data and add attributes to it, this will exclude the properties that you do not want/can't serialize. Something like the following

```cs
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ClassWithAction
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Action TheAction { get; set; }
}
```

[Here is Newtonsoft Reference](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)